# Why is this Action event null?

Tags: c#, events

I currently have 2 WinForms.

**FormA** creates an instance of **FormB**. I call the **ShowDialog()** method of **FormB**.

**FormB** defines `public event Action<SomeClass, string> Analyze`

When I click the **ProcessEvent** button of **FormB** I do the following:

```
Action<SomeClass, string> tempAction = Analyze;
if (tempAction != null)
{
  tempAction.Invoke(instanceOfSomeClass, someString);
}
```

But the event is not invoked because **tempAction** is null.

Why would it be null?

I define events in the same way in **FormA** and they work fine.

EDIT:

I have a presenter class that subscribes to the event:

```
formBInstance.Analyze += StartAnalyze
```

Comment: Why are you not just using `Analyze(instanceOfSomeClass, someString)` - which automatically handles whether there are subscribers or not

Comment: @Andras, no, it's not, it will throw `NullReferenceException` when there are no subscriptions

Comment: @Snowbear - Yeah of course it will - crumbs that's a noob one from me.  Obviously too early in the morning here; now I've had a coffee I can see the idiocy of that question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you must sign for event. If there is no subsribers Analyze will be null

```
FormB form = new FormB();
form.Analyze += OnAnanlyze; // define callback function
```

Comment: I have a presenter class thats registers itself with the event

Comment: You can use  Analyze.GetInvocationList() when you try to invoke event. this will return you all current subscribers for event

Comment: Looks like I forgot the Initialize an instance of my presenter therefore the there were no subscribers hence the event being null...oops :P This answer helped me figure that out. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Others have answered your original question. I'm just going to add some points that you should consider.

**Event initializer**

First of all, you can use `delegate {}´ as a initializer for all events to be able to skip the null check and also to make your events thread safe.

Example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public event EventHandler<TempActionArgs> TempAction = delegate {};
}
```

In that way you can invoke it by just using

```
TempAction(this, new TempActionArgs(someStrings);
```

No need for any checks.

**Using the standard event mechanism**

Don't use `Action<>` for events. Do use the standard `EventHandler`/`EventArgs` mechanism to make your application to look like any other .NET application. imho `Action<>` should only be used for temp invocation (and not during a objects lifetime). The LINQ methods are a perfect example.